# How to get the value of input from another ng-template

Tags: html, angular, ng-template

I have an input definition "nameInput" in an ng-template "temp1" and I want to read it's value inside another ng-template called "temp2". How can I do that?

```
<ng-template #temp1 ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value">
  <input id = "nameInput"
    type="text"
    [value]="value"
  />
</ng-template>
<ng-template #temp2 ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
  {{nameInput.value}}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: you don't have a formControl in your input field. So, there is nothing registers your input field's value or events